# How to capture event on click of close button in dojo Modaldialog?

Tags: dojo

I want to do some action on close button for ModalDialog box. I am using "idx.widget.modaldialog" in dojo. Is there any way to capture the close event?

Answer (score 0):

The `idx.widget.modaldialog` extends the `dijit.dialog` so you can implement the `onClose` method.

For example:

```
        onClose: lang.hitch(this, function(){
             // some code
        }),
```